# Help with manipulating some strings

Tags: c#, string

My strings are of this kind: `City (PR)` from a Database, where PR stands for Province.

At the end I want two separate variables. City and PR.

I have to do this with C#. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming cities don't contain `(` characters:

```
string s = "City (PR)";
int p = s.LastIndexOf("(");

string city = s.Substring(0, p).Trim();
string province = s.Substring(p + 1, s.Length - p - 2).Trim();
```

`city` is the substring from the first character up to but not including the last `(` character.
`province` is the substring from the first character after the last `(` to the end excluding the last character.

Comment: +1 nice and clean, and handles city names better; might consider using [`LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d.aspx) to make it even more robust

Comment: You should use Regex, like madgnome suggested

Answer (score 14):

You can use Regex and named groups.

```
string resultString = "New York (New York)";
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(?<City>[^(]*)\((?<PR>[^)]*)\)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var match = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
if (match.Success)
{
  string city = match.Groups["City"].Value.Trim();
  string province = match.Groups["PR"].Value;
}
```

### Regex explanation

`(?<City>[^(]*)\((?<PR>[^)]*)\)` :

- `(?<City>XXX)` defines a group named City

  - `[^(]*` matches any character that is not a `(` between 0 and unlimited times
- `\(` matches a `(` one time
- `(?<PR>XXX)` defines a group named PR

  - `[^)]*` matches any character that is not a `)` between 0 and unlimited times
- `\)` matches a `)` one time

Comment: Regex is the way to go! This was made for that kind of tasks.

Answer (score 10):

Regex?

You can divide your pattern into [capture groups](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+5+-+Capturing+regex+groups) and go from there.

```
(.*)(\(.*\))
```

That will capture the city in the first group and your PR/Province part in the second.

Edit: [madgnomes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874442/help-with-manipulating-some-strings/2874472#2874472) regex removes the paratheneses from the match, even if the Regex is getting scary at this point :)

Comment: I'm a noob with Regular Expressions, can u explain it better? Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't you escape the outside parens so the capture group has just "PR" in it, not "(PR)"?

Comment: To be a fair comparison to @dtb's excellent solution, this should be coded up. Its brevity is compelling now but I'm curious if that'll hold up

Comment: This solution is too simple but good as an example. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874442/help-with-manipulating-some-strings/2874525#2874525 for a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of methods on [`string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(VS.71).aspx) one of them being [Split](http://dotnetperls.com/string-split).

**Example**

```
var s = "City (PR)";
var words = s.Split(' ');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

That would print:

City

(PR)

You can also do it like this

```
var words = s.Split(' ');
var city = words[0];
var pr = words[1];
```

You can just remove the paranthesis with other string methods if you like.

One might argue that this is not the best way to do it. It's simple and give's you want you want. As others suggested, regex is probably the "cleanest" way to do it.

**Note**

If you want to support cities with spaces in the name, this method won't work out that well for you. I would then suggest one of the other answers posted.

Comment: What if the city is two words? Like New York?

Comment: That's over engineering it! Why would one think outside the box?.. Joke. Didn't think of cities with 2 words, since we don't have them were i live..

Comment: @Filip Ekberg
What about Lilla Edet? ;-)

Comment: @daft, Ok so 1 city here has a space in it, chaning my code would be like.. supporting IE6 ;) Anyways, my example works with basic string manipulation and now tells the OP that it won't work with spaces in the words.

Comment: @Filip
Only kidding. i struggled hard to come up with Lilla Edet to be honest. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the province is always in parenthesis, and the city name won't have any parenthesis, you can use the Split function.

```
string foo = "City (PR)";
string[] bar = foo.Split('(');
```

The bar variable will have the city in the first column of the array, and the province in the second (although you'll want to remove the right parenthesis).

Comment: this should work, even if i have to remove tha last parenthesis from PR with a substring.

Comment: Could probably get around this with `string[] bar = foo.Split("()".ToCharArray(),3)`, which would give you bar[0] is the city, and bar[1] at the province...

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you can modify the DB design to have a different field to hold whether it's a province or a state?  This is a horrible design, and in order to get around it you definitely need to write some ugly code... Something along the lines of

```
if(CityAndProvinceOrStateIndicator.Contains(" (PR)"))
{
   // This is a province.
   // Get the city name only
   string CityNameOnly = CityAndProvinceOrStateIndicator.Replace(" (PR)", "");


}
elseif...
```

Answer (score 1):

Although excellent parsing options have been mentioned, I'd just like to suggest that you consider going to the source and modifying your database query and possibly even the database itself.

Obviously that's not always possible, which is probably why you're asking the question in the way you are, but the fact that you're receiving data in this way implies to me that the data needs to be structured or obtained differently.

Comment: Is what I'm trying to do infact ;)

Comment: @Alex: Good. Always push for fixing the system "the right way", even if you don't get the chance to actually do it this time around. Without that push, your company will stagnate technologically, and that's bad. Unfortunately, it's rare for anyone outside of the technology to understand that, hence the need for the pushback.

Answer (score 0):

Let the following SQL SELECT statement do all the work for you:

```
SELECT [Name], [Address], 
       LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT([CityProv],CHARINDEX('(',[CityProv])-1))) as City, 
       LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING( [CityProv],
             CHARINDEX('(',[CityProv]) + 1,
             CHARINDEX(')',[CityProv]) - CHARINDEX('(',[CityProv]) - 1))) as Prov, 
       [PostalCode]
FROM Stackoverflow
```

Here is the dataset I created for testing:

Joel,1 Software St,NewYork (NY),12345
Jeff,321 Horror Lane,San somewhere ( CAL),90210
Zamboni,888 Wpf Rd,Vancouver (Britsh Columbia ),V0S1A0
Bill,7 Main St,Vista( WA ),77777